# Why do I run into an error when I call the map() method in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently ranking a collection of webpages

```
['page1 page3','page2 page1','page4 page1','page3 page1','page4 page2','page3 page4']
```

using the PageRank algorithm in PySpark, where the items are in the format of 'source_page target_page'. 
Firstly, I output its outgoing neighbors in a list for each page, i.e.

```
linksRDD = rdd.map(lambda x:tuple(x.split(" "))).map(lambda x:(x[0],[x[1]])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y).collect()
```

`linksRDD` looks like this:

```
[('page1', ['page3']),
 ('page2', ['page1']),
 ('page4', ['page1', 'page2']),
 ('page3', ['page1', 'page4'])]
```

Then, I proceeded to calculate the contribution of each page's outgoing link. First I parallelised `linksRDD` to create a new RDD `linksRDD_2`:

```
linksRDD_2=sc.parallelize(linksRDD)
```

Then, I defined the function `computeContribs()`:

```
def computeContribs(neighbors, rank):
    for neighbor in neighbors:
        yield (neighbor, rank/len(neighbors))
```

After that, I tried to run the following line of code:

```
for iteration in range(10):
    contribs = linksRDD_2.map(lambda x:computeContribs(x[1],1.0)).collect()
```

However, I encountered the following error, which I suspect can be boiled down to `TypeError: can't pickle generator objects`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-7bb802f34ae5> in <module>()
      1 for iteration in range(10):
      2     # calculate the contribution of each page's outgoing link
----> 3     contribs =  linksRDD_2.map(lambda x:computeContribs(list(x[1]),1.0)).collect()
      4     contribs
      5 

3 frames
/content/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 26.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 26.0 (TID 53, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/content/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/content/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 404, in dump_stream
    bytes = self.serializer.dumps(vs)
  File "/content/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 583, in dumps
    return pickle.dumps(obj, protocol)
TypeError: can't pickle generator objects

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:592)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/content/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/content/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 404, in dump_stream
    bytes = self.serializer.dumps(vs)
  File "/content/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 583, in dumps
    return pickle.dumps(obj, protocol)
TypeError: can't pickle generator objects

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:592)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

I don't quite know how to solve this error; can anyone give me a hand? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't completely follow, what you are trying to achieve as part of "computeContribs" function. Can you provide the desired output you are looking for, probably by converting RDD to DF it might be easier achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: @HussainBohra actually after calling the `computeContribs` function i still need to update each page's page rank score by summing up all the contribution scores of incoming links for each page before being able to generate the desired output, but I'm still stuck at the function part for the time being.

Comment: @HussainBohra actually the `computeContribs` function is used to compute the contribute score of each outgoing link of a certain page in the collection, for example if a page's rank is 1.0 and it has 2 outgoing links, each link will have a contribution of 0.5. The function will be called repeatedly for at most ten times (`range(10)`) until the pages' ranks remain the same after a new iteration. The desired output is just tuples of each page and its corresponding finalised page rank score, e.g. `[('page4', 0.7109375), ('page2', 0.375), ('page3', 1.484375), ('page1', 1.4296875)]`